# how to display calendar view as the first view in odoo

Tags: xml, odoo-8, calendarview

I have a menu in my module. When i click on the menu, i want calendar view to be open. I also have tree, form,calendar,and kanban views. Right now In my module, when i click the menu list view is showing first. Instead of list view i would like to show calendar view?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usually when we click on a menu list view is shown as the first view. To show the calendar view use the view_id field inside the action record.

Example

```
    <record id="open_view_project_all" model="ir.actions.act_window">
         ---------------------
            <field name="view_id" ref="here give the id of calendar view"/>
         ---------------------
   </record>
```

---

menu item as follows....

```
<menuitem action="open_view_project_all" id="menu_projects" name="Projects" />
```

Answer (score 2):

Find this type of line in your xml file,

```
<field name="view_mode">tree,form,calender,kanban</field>
```

and change it like this,

```
  <field name="view_mode">calender,tree,form,kanban</field>
```

Whichever view is listed first in this line it will be displayed first.So search for view_mode field and make your desired changes,restart the server and upgrade the module then you can see your desired changes.